# CSS align image with text

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do i style it so that the image could be inline? I think its being caused by the breakline in the text of 'community services' Thanks for the help in advance ! 
PS: An additional question, is it possible to align the things i have currently in the middle without using the text-align:center element in displayCategories? As i want to add some more sentence but i doesn't want it to be centralized.

My HTML code:

```css
#displayCategories {
  background-color: #FAFAFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#displayCategories .imgSlot {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="displayCategories">
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Amenities</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Attractions</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Community<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Services</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Environment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Education</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top` in you `imgSlot` class to align to the top of the images. By default, `inline-block` elements are aligned to `baseline` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
  #displayCategories {
    background-color:#FAFAFF;
    text-align:center;
  }

  #displayCategories::after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }

  #displayCategories .imgSlot {
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*New Attribute*/
    vertical-align:top;
  }

  .caption {
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left:5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="displayCategories">
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Amenities</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Attractions</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Community<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Services</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Environment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="imgSlot">
    <img src="img/cateIcon.png" />
    <span class="caption">Education</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to give the #displayCategories container a `display:flex`, with `justify-content: center`. Then remove the `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` declarations from .imgSlot:

```css
img{
  max-height:50px;
}

#displayCategories {
    background-color:#FAFAFF;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
  }

  #displayCategories .imgSlot {
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .caption {
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left:5px;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="displayCategories">
          <div class="imgSlot">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <span class="caption">Amenities</span>
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlot">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <span class="caption">Attractions</span>
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlot">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <span class="caption">Community<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Services</span>
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlot">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <span class="caption">Environment</span>
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlot">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" />
            <span class="caption">Education</span>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why not use StacksSnippets (the `<>` button in the editor)? Your answer would be a lot clearer if we didn't have to go off site to see it in context.

Comment: Ok, I edited it with StacksSnippets.

Comment: Thx.... much better